With ASP.NET and C#, font size is decreased when exporting Crystal Report to PDF
I found this, I needed to create a registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\Export\PDF\ForceLargerFonts

And then to set ForceLargerFonts to the value word: 00000001.
And it works fine now.
It is working on my desktop, but I have the same issue on the server for ASP.NET web client side.
How can I make changes in server registry to achieve the same result, or is there any another option for server?

Use the same approach but with HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE instead of HKEY_CURRENT_USER.
Reminder: depending on whether the Crystal runtime is 32-bit or 64-bit, you need to pick the correct location in the registry.
